# Ruby billboard with em-websocket

Tags: ruby, web-services, sinatra, em-websocket, em-websocket-client

I try to build a billboard for displaying messages in a browser initiated by the server using sinatra. The obviest thing to do in the servercode was like this:

server:

```
require 'em-websocket'
require 'yajl'
require 'haml'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thin'

$channel = EM::Channel.new

EventMachine.run do
  class App < Sinatra::Base
    get '/' do
      haml :index
    end
  end

  EventMachine::WebSocket.start(:host => '0.0.0.0', :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen {
      sid = $channel.subscribe { |msg| ws.send msg }
      ws.onmessage { |msg| $channel.push msg}
# the text I periodically send to the server and want to be visible in the connected webbrowsers
      1.upto(5) {|i| sleep 3; ws.send "Hello #{i}"} #had to remove this
    }
  end
  App.run!({:port => 3000})
end
```

index.haml

```
!!!
%html{:lang => "en"}
  %head
    %link{:href => "/css/bootstrap.css", :rel => "stylesheet"}
  %body
    %div#show
    %script{:src => "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"}
    %script{:src => "/js/bootstrap.js"}
    %script{:src => "/js/app.js"}
```

app.js

```
$(function(){
  ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
  ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
    if (evt.data!='done'){
      document.getElementById("show").innerHTML = evt.data; 
    }
  };
});
```

But the text is shown in the browser all at once after the last sleep, so only the last line is visible. I can't seem to send stuff from the serverside once the connection is made, only as reaction to an incomming message.

So I tried it with a Ruby client like below which worked but I have to make a new connection every time I send some text, putting the loop in the .callback or .stream method doesn't work.

```
require 'em-websocket-client'

def send text
  EM.run do
    conn = EventMachine::WebSocketClient.connect("ws://localhost:8080")

    conn.callback do
      conn.send_msg text
      conn.send_msg "done"
    end

    conn.stream do |msg|
      puts "<#{msg}>"
      if msg.data == "done"
        conn.close_connection
      end
    end

    conn.disconnect do
      EM::stop_event_loop
    end
  end
end

1.upto(5) do |i|
  sleep 3
  send "Hello #{i}"
end
```

I'm sure there has to better way to achive this, which way please ?